# Increasing delay over a stream?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have the following, and it does work, it keeps increasing the delay and eventually timing out which is what I wanted.

But because I am using Concatmap i lose the original value from the interval.

```
   let x = 1
    let source2$ = interval(500)
      .pipe(

        concatMap(() => {
          x++
          let newtime = x * 500
          console.log("newtime ", newtime)
          return of(5).pipe(delay(newtime))
        }),
        timeout(3000),
        map((data) => {
          return 'Source 2: ' + data
        })
      )
```

so it prints Source 2: 5.. where as i want it to print the value of the interval.

I got working what i wanted using the concatmap but i think its the wrong operator as I lose the original value.

Can somebody help?

***More info***

TO summarize, all i would like to do is emit values using the interval and after each emit increase the delay time - eventually it hits the timeout of 3000 ms and errors out.

Comment: `concatMap` receives the value that triggered its projection function like `concatMap(value => {})` so you can `value` later if that's what you are asking

Comment: Yes, i suppose that would work. Is there some other kind of operator that will allow me run the delay but not return another observable. I think I sort of it got it working by mistake but I can't stop feeling i am doing it wrong

Comment: I think I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: I updated the message with a summary of what i am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've mentioned in comments that you can use `concatMap` for this that receives ever increasing index from `interval`:

```
concatMap(index => {
  let newtime = index * 500
  console.log("newtime ", newtime)
  return of(index).pipe(delay(newtime))
}),
```

Notice, that I'm returning the value back to the stream by `of(index)`.

I think I understand what were you concerned about returning another Observable. Since you want to emit items in sequence (emit one only after the previous one completes) then you have to use `concatMap` with another inner Observable. There isn't a special operator only for this functionality because this is "composable behavior" which means you can achieve this behavior by combining existing operators.

Comment: Yes, that does work. That's what I was thinking is that there was an alternative way of doing things. Now you explained it, it seems better, Thanks!

Comment: @martin How will you incrementally increase RxJS delay without using interval? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64625561/3073280

Answer (score 0):

```
const source2$ = interval(500)
      .pipe(
        map(x => x * 500),
        switchMap(x => timer(x)),
        timeout(3000),
        map(data =>  'Source 2: ' + data)
       )
```

UPDATE:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-iywcm6?devtoolsheight=60

```
const source2$ = interval(500)
      .pipe(
        tap(x => console.log('Tick before delay', x)),
        concatMap(x => timer((x + 1) * 500).pipe(mapTo(x))),        
        tap(x => console.log('Tick after delay', x)),
        map(data =>  'Source 2: ' + data),
        timeout(3000)
       ).subscribe(
         (data) => console.log(data),
         e => console.error('Timeout', e))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It timeout immediately. Also doesn't switchmap change the observable so I would lose the value

Comment: @MarkSmith, I misunderstood your original question. Check if updated version works for you.

Comment: How do I incrementally increase RxJS delay without using interval? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64625561/3073280