# RxJS - How to incrementally increase the delay time without using interval?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I want to incrementally increase the delay for this:

```
const source = from(839283, 1123123, 63527, 4412454); // note: this is random
const spread = source.pipe(concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(delay(1000)))); // how to incrementally increase the delay where the first item emits in a second, the second item emits in three seconds, the third item emits in five seconds, and the last item emits in seven seconds.
spread.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

I'm aware of using interval to incrementally increase the delay time as below. But I also need to consume this source `const source = from(839283, 1123123, 63527, 4412454);`

```
const source = interval(1000); // But I also need to use have this from(839283, 1123123, 63527, 4412454)
const spread = source.pipe(concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(delay(value * 200))));
spread.subscribe(value => console.log(value
```

How to incrementally increase the delay time when starting with `const source = from(839283, 1123123, 63527, 4412454);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the index of the emitted value and calculate the delay based on that.

```ts
concatMap((value, index) => {
  return of(value).pipe(delay((index > 2 ? 7 : index) * 1000));
})
```

Here is a stackblitz for a complete example with your snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jjmlta?devtoolsheight=60

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [`concatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) is an index which can be multiplied by 1000 to give the sequence 0, 1000, 2000... The sequence 1000, 3000, 5000... can then be created with `1000 * (i * 2 + 1)`:

```js
const {concatMap, delay, from, of} = rxjs;

from([839283, 1123123, 63527, 4412454])
  .pipe(concatMap((value, i) =>
    of(value).pipe(delay(1000 * (i * 2 + 1)))
  ))
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```